# How to programmatically receive email in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, azure

I'm running an Azure website and would like to programmatically (in C#) receive email sent to my (sub) domain.

For example:
The website's domain is www.mydomain.com.
I want to receive all emails sent to customer@email.mydomain.com and then programmatically act based on the *customer* part of the address. I also need to read the email, subject and attachments and store them in a database.

I have tried to find good solutions on how to implement somthing like this but haven't found any so far. Hope someone has an idea how this could be done?

Comment: so essentially you want step by step instructions on how to make a mail server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using SendGrid available as an add on through the Azure marketplace, you can start with the free account.

Then once you have an account, you get access to the [Inbound Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) that allows you to receive emails sent to a domain/subdomain and act on, in your case, the piece before the @ sign.

Here's an example of using the webhook with C#: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/Webhook_Examples/csharp.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do exactly what I need. Also figured out that Mandrill can do the same for a cheaper price: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

Comment: Just checked today, their price plans seem to be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use a service like SendGrid that does this and much more. You can purchase a subscription through the Azure marketplace or start a trial before you buy.